# how to prevent my jquery modal from scrolling to the top of the window?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Hi i think its ugly when I click on form button the modal brings user up to the start of the page. I would rather it stay where the user is currently on the page. Is this possible?

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
        $("#overlay-modal").fadeIn();
    });
    $(document).mousedown(function(e){
            var clicked = $(e.target);
        if (clicked.is('.inner-modal') || clicked.parents().is('.inner-modal')){
                return;
            } else { $('#overlay-modal').hide();
        }
    });
 });
```

this is what i currently have. I tried to add an anchor tag at the bottom of where i would like the page to stay but this didnt work. I also try moving the form's location on the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The click event needs to return false, to prevent the link from sending you to the top... `#`

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
  // your stuff
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Two reasons: the `#` hash sends you to a specific id in a web page, when it's by itself it just sends you to the top. Clicking a link with `href="#" or href=""` sends you to the top. Returning false tells the browser that the click event will not proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I think it may be more advantageous to **e.preventDefault();** in your code than **return false;**...

```
$(".buttons").click(function(){
        $("#overlay-modal").fadeIn();
    });
    $(document).mousedown(function(e){
            var clicked = $(e.target);
        if (clicked.is('.inner-modal') || clicked.parents().is('.inner-modal')){
                e.preventDefault();
            } else { $('#overlay-modal').hide();
        }
    });
 });
```

This primarily has to do with event bubbling which **return false** does not stop.